# Istio 1.15 how to local rate limit by IP address

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy, rate

I am looking to local rate limit via istio 1.15 by ip address. Per some other examples I've found it seems I should be able to set

```
key: remote_address
```

however this config is nowhere in the example in the istio documentation. Is there an example of a very simple, local rate limit via ip address?

Is it also possible to attach the envoyFilter to the ingress itself (per https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/local_rate_limit_filter#config-http-filters-local-rate-limit) as opposed to on a per pod level?

My goal is a simple global rate limit on all requests going through the istio virtualservice/gateway to be ratelimited by IP

Comment: Maybe from this example https://istio.io/v1.0/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limiting In this task, you configure Istio to rate limit traffic to productpage based on the IP address of the originating client. You will use X-Forwarded-For request header as the client IP address. You will also use a conditional rate limit that exempts logged in users.